# 'red' vs 'that are red'

Tags: grammar, difference, vocabulary

What is the difference between:

> **lines that are red** are representing (...)

vs.

> **red lines** are representing (...)

---

and

> **lines that start with** the letter A (...)

vs.

> **lines starting with**  the letter A (...)

---

I'm interested in the meaning, usage and which one sounds better to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider these choices:

> lines that are red are representing (...)

vs.

> the red lines are representing (...)

vs.

> the red lines represent (...)

Without knowing all the details of the surrounding textual context, simple brevity is often preferable. The best phrasing is last one. "The red lines represent."  Next, "the red lines are representing" is present continuous, which implies an action that is proceeding. However, the red lines are not so much involved in a continuous action (running, jumping) which is proceeding over time. The simple present would be better.

Comparing "red lines" to "lines that are red", you'd only choose the second one if a particular emphasis were required. To stress the idea. For example, "Not the blue lines. The - lines - that - are - red. Got it?" There are other situations and examples also, however the common case will be to only say "red lines" because it's concise, clear, and understandable. Thus, why add extra words?

Next,

> lines that start with the letter A (...)

vs.

> lines starting with the letter A (...)

Are fairly similar to each other.

One perspective: If a word can be eliminated without obscuring the meaning, then it should be. The 2nd choice is preferable.

Another perspective: In everyday usage of the language, "lines that start with the letter A" does not sound incorrect or overly wordy. This type of phrasing will often be the natural choice. The goal is not *always* to remove every extra word. If you are presenting instructional material to students, and wish to be official and proper, then additional words can be an advantage. "lines that start with the letter A (...)"

Comment: Thank you for that, very informative, especially the remarks on the usage. Being concise is a tricky thing. Have a nice day!

Comment: I didn't want to create a new question, can I ask you here how about this *all of the files that were modified* vs *all of the modified files*? Is the second option better?

Comment: @Aduku , both are grammatically correct. It depends on the context and usage. It's not that one is absolutely always better.  If it's well understood what's being discussed, then "modified files" is sort of shorthand.  If a new topic is being discussed, "what about the files that were modified? What about those?"  then maybe it shouldn't be abbreviated. etc.